# ¿Cómo subir un proyecto symfony a un Host?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, hosting

**Contexto:** Desarrolle un proyecto usando Symfony 5, soy nuevo usando el framework y trato de subirlo a Hostinger.

**Pasos que seguí:**

1. Borre las carpetas que se mencionan en este video: [Video Tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEXufFNmDG0&t=682s)
2. Use el comando `composer dump-env prod` para configurar en modo producción.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Use el comando `composer require symfony/apache-pack` para generar el htaccess

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Subí el proyecto a Hostinger con Fillezilla

-> Quedando la carpeta public_html de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El error:**

Leí por ahí que es cosa de re-direccionar cosas, pero la verdad no se bien como hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: asi de primeras, te falta la carpeta de config en el raiz. esta buscando `bundles.php` dentro de una carpeta `config`. de todas formas este tipo de "despliegue" no es muy comun al final con este tipo de aplicaciones (utilizando frameworks como symfony)...

Comment: Necesitas tener todo tu código subido al servidor para que funcione. Por ejemplo, no veo la carpeta "src". "public_html" es el directorio raiz de tu espacio en el servidor? De ser así deberías apuntar tu doc_root a "public_html/public"

Comment: Estoy en una situación parecida a la tuya, tratando de desplegar una App en un sitio remoto. Como bien dice @Muc son necesarias las carpetas con el código en el sitio remoto para que la aplicación funcione, para que esto no sea un dolor de cabeza constante lo más simple es crear un repositorio git en local y luego sincronizarlo con la carpeta del sitio remoto. Para mi [este tutorial](https://gist.github.com/Nilpo/8ed5e44be00d6cf21f22) ha sido fundamental. He logrado de una forma sorprendentemente fácil de subir al servidor mi proyecto, creado y probado en local ...

Comment: ... Cuando la configuración está terminada, si en un futuro cambias algo en local, haces un `git push live` y esos cambios pasan al servidor. Todo eso lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Luego está la cuestión de que el despliegue funcione bien. En la web de Symfony [explican varias cosas que se deben hacer antes de desplegar el proyecto](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html), habría que hacer lo indicado allí en local, antes de sincronizar la primera vez con git y si no funciona entonces quizá haya que cambiar más cosas en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Has usado la base de datos de Hostinger? De ser así, En la conexión, ¿has puesto localhost? yo estoy desplegando también una aplicación symfony y me da un error 500 (creo que por la BD)

Comment: Hola user20725278, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, 

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.